# How to use backgroundImage css in styled component having typescript

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have following styled component

```
const StyledBackIcon = styled.div(imgsrc => ({
    backgroundImage: url`${imgsrc}`
 }))
```

Now Here it throws an error compilation for `url`.

how to fix this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
   const StyledBackIcon = styled.div(imgsrc => ({
      backgroundImage: url`${imgsrc}`
   }))
```

write

```
   const StyledBackIcon = styled.div(imgsrc => ({
      backgroundImage: `url${imgsrc}`
   }))
```

see the backtic starts before url.

Answer (score 0):

While styled-components does writing support CSS using a JS object instead of strings, such as in the example below - referenced from [here in the docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#style-objects):

```
const PropsBox = styled.div(props => ({
  background: props.background,
  height: '50px',
  width: '50px'
}));
```

I don't think it's really necessary in this case? I tried them both out here: [link to sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/green-darkness-vlk6e?file=/src/button.js). The examples in the sandbox use the [CSS background property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp), a shorthand property that includes the background-image property.

```
const StyledButton = styled.button`
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: white url('${(props) => props.icon}') no-repeat center/90%;
`;

export const Button = ({ img, handleClick }) => (
  <StyledButton onClick={handleClick} icon={img} />
);
```

Good luck!